# Error When Run NextCloud Docker AIO On Windows 10 Pro

Tags: docker, server, nextcloud

I have been trying to run the Next Cloud Docker AIO for Windows 10 Pro and I keep getting an error.

The command is:

```
docker run ^
--init ^
--sig-proxy=false ^
--name nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer ^
--restart always ^
--publish 80:80 ^
--publish 8080:8080 ^
--publish 8443:8443 ^
--volume nextcloud_aio_mastercontainer:/mnt/docker-aio-config ^
--volume //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro ^
nextcloud/all-in-one:latest
```

and the error is:

```
docker: error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/create?name=nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I want to make a file server to get away from google drive and Microsoft OneDrive, but I currently can't I'm new to docker, so I have no idea what I'm doing.

I have not tried anything because I have no experience with docker I did try to restart though and I do know how to understand PowerShell and command prompt, but this seems different.